# Get start-up progress of Aurelia?

Tags: promise, aurelia

Aurelia loads quite a bit on start up. I notice you can specify when Aurelia starts-up and that it will return a Promise.

```
aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
```

Its not clear to me if it is possible to hook into the promise to figure out how many tasks there are and when each completes?

So my question is: **Is it possible deduce the progress of Aurelia's loading?** Say, for example, if you wanted to set the percentage of a Progress bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Aurelia's loading time is SystemJS loading files from the server.  Presumably, you will be bundling for production so I believe the correct way to show a loading bar would be to monitor the progress of the bundle request and display that.

I don't believe Aurelia has a concept of loading time because under the hood, Aurelia isn't really waiting on a set of things, it just requests things as it needs them and some of those come from the remote server.

Comment: that's true, though I really wish we did have some notion of startup progress

Comment: One thing to note: there is an outstanding bug with SystemJS which causes the loader to pause on startup (the more modules that are added the longer the pause). Startup time should be reduced when that's fixed

Comment: @Charleh - is there a bug tracking number we can watch to see the progress of this issue?

Comment: It's been addressed a couple of months ago - times are down to Shinobi ninja star dodging split second speeds!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding a small JavaScript in the index.html which checks how many require modules were loaded. It works like a charm. Please check the how-to and example here:

http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/a-real-loading-indication-for-aurelia-and-requirejs/

Cheers